# Feathersjs TypeError: app.publish is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, feathersjs

I'm new in feathersjs so i'm creating a chat app following the documentation but i have this problem
can u help me?
i can't understand what is going on
app.js code

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');

const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');   
const helmet = require('helmet');


// * Importing Services
const MessageService = require('./services/MessageService');


// * Initialization
const app = express(feathers()); 

// * Middlewares
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(helmet());

// * Configurations
app.configure(socketio); // ? Config Socketio realtime API's
app.configure(express.rest()); // ? Config REST Services

// * Create a Public folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/public')));

// * Register Services
app.use('/messages', new MessageService());

 
// * Connections
app.on('connection', conn => app.channel('stream').join(conn)); // ? Connect to the Stream Channel

// * Publish events to stream
app.publish(data => app.channel('stream'));


module.exports = app;
```

and thats my error

```
app.publish(data => app.channel('stream'));
    ^

TypeError: app.publish is not a function
```

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with your example - but I'm not familiar with FeatherJS. Have you tried running their code example https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/starting.html#our-first-app to see if that works and if it does work back from there?

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.configure(socketio);` needs to be `app.configure(socketio());` (see [API docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#app-configure-socketio)).

Comment: i'm not using typescript, i'm using js